# Interacting with BLE Cycle Trainer

Tags: bluetooth, dart, flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

My current is on Flutter using Dart and working with Bluetooth low energy devices. I have the basics up using [this](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_blue) library and am able to do the following

```
1. Search for devices and list
2. Connect to device
3. Retrieve services and read characteristic values
4. Subscribe to changes on characteristics.
```

In order to interact with device correctly I need to read and write from the correct services/characteristics to read data and set things like resistance on the flywheel

I have used the below link and have started mapping out the services, however although the reading can be worked out. The writing to characteristics is a bit out of my reach.

https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.service.cycling_power.xml

The question is.

> Does any have experience working BLE cycle trainers and could provide
>   some insight into how to read and manage services and characteristics
>   appropriately?